# Podcasts app displaying duplicates, one with a cloud icon

Tags: ios, podcasts, podcasts.app

I recently updated my iPhone 5s to iOS 11 and now Podcasts seems to be totally broken.

All I want to do is play Podcasts I download - preferably on iTunes.

Now I see seemingly identical Podcasts with a download link.

Is there anyway to fix the display of podcasts to remove the duplicates?

The following shows part of the problem: identical Podcasts one with a download link.

[image]

Comment: I switched to Downcast when they removed Poscasts from the Music app as Podcasts is not usable

Comment: Could you please provide more information about how your Podcasts app looks like and what you are intending to do and does not work? I'm not much into Podcasts lately but I started my Podcasts app on my iPhone SE and it looks pretty much like it would work. Don't get me wrong, just add some pictures or something that explains your issue :)

Comment: I've removed the additional questions to focus on the problem of duplicate podcast listings, since the other questions would be too broad such as the interface being ‘cluttered’. If you're looking for an alternative app, ask a separate [tag:software-recommendation] question with full details of the app you're looking for.

Comment: well first thing to try would be to reset everything in the podcast app by deleting everything and start from scratch. It's annoying, but this should last like forever since the podcast app got updated completely since iOS11.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems to happen when I download an episode in the iPhone and later sync with iTunes. It creates a duplicate where: one episode lacks of description and the other one shows the iCloud icon and can never be downloaded. Very annoying.